# alternative to CopyOnWriteArrayList for frequent writes, occasional iterating

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that is to be cached and shared across multiple threads indefinitely. Operations include frequent adds and removes, plus occasional iterating over it.

The `ArrayList` lives in a wrapper class which manages access to it:

```
public class MyListWrapper<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    private List<T> innerList = new ArrayList<T>();

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return innerList.listIterator();
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        innerList.add(element);
        //app-specific logic
    }

    //remove(T), etc in the same pattern...
}
```

I'm currently making preparations for thread safety.  At first, [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) seemed like the best answer, but its performance concerns me, since modifications will be made more often than anything else.

Would a manual change to the wrapper class such as this be a better alternative?:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new ArrayList<T>(innerList).listIterator();
}

//plus concurrency tweaks for any non-atomic modifications to innerList
```

Please help me find the best approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using a `Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<T, Boolean>());` This will give you a concurrent hash set which will give you near O(1) add and remove.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I needed. +1 for teaching me something. Thanks

Comment: Its iterator is thread safe so you don't need to synchronize and might not need to take a copy.

Comment: In java 1.8 I guess that method has been renamed Collections.newSetFromMap

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Thank you for the correction, it was always called than. ;)

Answer (score 5):

A possibility is to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue if you can live with the Queue interface instead of the List. I would argue that more use cases than you expect may be satisfied with a Queue. One key advantage of List is random access (based on index), but in a concurrent situation random access is neither necessary nor desirable.

ConcurrentLinkedQueue is an excellent concurrent implementation of Queue.

Comment: +1 I did realize since asking this question that random access was unimportant, and that it was unnecessary to use a List in the first place.