# A concurrent collection that maintains insertion order

Tags: java, collections, concurrentmodification

I'm looking for a concurrent list that can maintain the insertion order. Does anyone have some good recommendation ?

I look at some from guava e.g. SetFromMap, but they are deprecated in the new version.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a list or a set? Because lists maintain insertion order by definition.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a concurrent List in Java's JDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916385/is-there-a-concurrent-list-in-javas-jdk)

Comment: I depends on your use case: Do you have a lot of write operations? Do you have mostly read op and few wrtie op? Do you have a lot of elements to store into your collection?

Comment: @Nicolas I expect to have more write operations and read operations

Comment: What about the total amount of elements in your collection? About 10/100/1 000/10 000... elements?

Comment: Maximum will be 10k elements

Comment: If so the CopyOnWriteArrayList is clearly not the right candidate, have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074111/alternative-to-copyonwritearraylist-for-frequent-writes-occasional-iterating

Comment: @Nicolas can you make the comment as answer? Since it is what im looking for.

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa well, thank you for proposing but I don't want to benefit from other responses but I proposed my own response to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have mostly read operations, very few write operations and you don't have too much elements then you can use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as it is a lock free implementation of a `List` for read operations such that it can hardly be faster but it is **very costly for the write operations** as for every single write, it re-builds the entire `List` to be able to provide a new read-only copy for the next read operations.

As in your case, you have many write operations and a lot of elements to put in your collection, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` **is clearly not** an option for you.

What I suggest in your case, is to use one thread-safe `Queue` that you can find into the `java.util.concurrent` package. According to your context and your JDK version the best choice may change, but if you don't specifically need a `blocking queue` or a `deque` but only a `pure collection`, the best choices are probably `ArrayBlockingQueue`, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or `LinkedBlockingQueue`  but according to this [benchmark result](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/java-best-practices-queue-battle-and.html) (a little bit old), the `LinkedBlockingQueue` provides the best overall performances.

**But when we talk about performances, the first and most important advice is: *always test on your target environment, it is the only valid way to know what is the best choice for you*.**

Answer (score 4):

A `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a `List` that both maintains insertion order (as expected from a `List`) and allows concurrent access.

Docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: This assumes a very low write rate, but it's the closest match.

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum will be 10k elements

If you have an extremely low update rate, CopyOnWriteArrayList is a possible solution. This will allow concurrent reads efficiently.

The problem you have is that concurrent and ordered are opposite concerns. To have ordering, you need to serialize updates to determine the order.  To have concurrency you need to discard ordering.

There is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, however this only allows concurrent read (1) and write (1)